# Angular Material Slider Data Binding while dragging

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to control the audio volume with a material slider. Just like the YouTube audio slider. I use two way data binding like this:

```
  <mat-slider min="0" max="1" step="0.01" [(value)]="settingsService.audioTick.volume"></mat-slider>
```

The problem is, the value will only get updated when I stop dragging the slider. Which is a bad user experience because I don't immediately hear if that is a good volume. So I somehow need to do data binding while dragging.

Here is a StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/angular/rojampjmlap

Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `[value]` property binding syntax to pass `someValue` as an `@Input` to `MatSlider`. `MatSlider` has an `@Output` property defined named `input` that gets triggered when the `input` value changes. You can listen to that and simply re-assign whatever is returned as the `$event` data to `someValue`.

Here, give this a try:

**Template:**

```
<mat-slider 
  (input)="someValue = $event.value" 
  [value]="someValue">
</mat-slider>

{{ someValue }}
```

**Component:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class SliderOverviewExample {
  someValue = 0;
}
```

Here's an Updated [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-slider-with-instant-change?file=app/slider-overview-example.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind to the `input` Output property to get the live data change. Example:

```html
<mat-slider
  min="0"
  max="1"
  step="0.01"
  (input)="settingsService.audioTick.volume = $event.value"
  [value]="settingsService.audioTick.volume" />
```

Comment: You **shouldn't** two-way bind `[(value)]` and also bind `(input)` to the same property. Just read bind `[value]`.

Comment: Thank you! Works like it should